# APC can not differentiate multiple symfony sites

Tags: php, caching, symfony, xampp, apc

I ran into a very bizarre problem today, I had created a cms like site with symfony2  today I created a new directory and copied the site here because I wanted to work on a project base on that, after doing some editing I realized when I open the first site it also shows the second one, they even share the session !!!

**To summarize** :

1. I had site A
2. copied site A and renamed it to B
3. edited B
4. whenever I open either one of A or B it shows the same thing ( the
   first one I open after xampp starts )

P.S : I have changed the database and global secret parameters for the new site with no luck

Has anyone faced a similar problem before ?
thank you :)

**Edit**  : the problem is with **APC** caching is there any way to make APC realize these are two different apps ?

Comment: did you check `htaccess` and `hosts` file.

Comment: @Rafee what should I look for in those files ?

Comment: `.htaccess` file in your project directory and `hosts` file in windows `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\`

Comment: No I mean what should I change in those files the hosts file seems fine and I think the problem is with some sort of caching because when I start xampp if I go to B it show B correctly, and if I restart xampp and go to A it shows A correctly, whichever is visited first after xampp start ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the front controller (`web/app.php`) you can define a prefix to prevent cache conflicts. Make sure this prefix is unique for each application.

```
// web/app.php

...

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// Change 'sf2' to a unique prefix in order to prevent cache key conflicts
// with other applications also using APC.

$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);

....
```

Comment: This doesn't go far enough for me. Within the app when I call apc_store it uses the string I put in with no prefix (the 'sf2' listed above). so if two apps manual store something with the same key they'll still clash.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look into and disable APC caching if its enabled.

Comment: The problem is with APC caching.

Comment: But what if I want to keep it enabled, is there a way to give each app a unique identifier to help APC distinguish them ?